# mojito and the best way to connect with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, mojito

i started using mojito yahoo framework and i wanted to use with mongodb for building a simple application but no resources for how to include mongodb as an external module with mojito app, i was reading about mongoskin which is a wrapper of node-mongodb-native ,now what confuse me is HOWTO connect the mojito application with mongodb so any suggestions ??

i read the develpers notes [of yahoo mojito docs](http://developer.yahoo.com/cocktails/mojito/docs/topics/mojito_extensions.html) of howto extends mojito addon but it still not clear for me how to do this with mongodb

thanks :)

Answer (score 1):

I was developing with Mojito in two projects, what about if you simply install the mongodb drivers for nodejs, just like this tutorial explains http://mongodb.github.com/node-mongodb-native/api-articles/nodekoarticle1.html, and then you start calling the nodejs mongodb objects inside your mojito controllers or models to connect to your database?